# Is there any possibility to call one controller function in another controller function in EF in .net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Here is my sample Code :

```
public ActionResult Index() // Base Function
{
    // here, I want to call Copy function
    return view();
}

public Actionresult Copy() // child function which I want to use in base function
{
    return res;
}
```

How can exactly do like that? If you will provide me suggestion using ViewModel, It will be more good for me.Thanks!

Comment: Maybe, I do not understand exactly the problem, but simply call return Copy from Index method.

Comment: It is like, I want to do something like inheritance in.net MVC.I want to use the functionality of Copy function in Index when I call the   Copy function in the index.

Comment: Please show us what exactly the Copy method is doing and how it is gonna be used.

Comment: I have already got the answer. thanks